# How to configure elasticsearch PHP client?

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch

Now ElasticSearch gives results if query is more then 2 symbols. How to configure elasticsearch php that search works after minimum 1 entered symbol?

This is example of sourse:

```
{
"_index": "users",
"_type": "profiles",
"_id": "7",
"_version": 2,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"id": "544",
"type": "1",
"name": "Babaev",
"photo": "/06/07/07/38/145x145/667200b3d3beffd4178ccd05903544d8.jpg",
"country": "Mordoc",
"SpecializationName": null,
"rating": "0"
}
}
```

Comment: I tried do query via web-terminal as: `_search?q=name:babaev`. It gives me result, but `ba` does not

Comment: May be probles is that İ use `$params['body']['query']['match']['name']`? Match?